# Automatically wrapping & unwrapping wrappers.proto types in protobuf.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, protobuf.js

I have been using protobuf.js (command line tools) pbjs and pbts to generate my js and typescript classes for my defined .proto files. I get a json response from my backend API that I am looking to deserialize into the protobuf generated classes. the recommended way to do this is to use the fromObject method which takes in the json object.
Let's say I have

```
message ChangeEvent {
  string source = 1;
  google.protobuf.StringValue code = 2;
}
```

I'd like to be able to pass in:

```
const changeEventWithCode = {
  source = 'test',
  code = 'code',
}

const changeEventWithoutCode = {
  source = 'test',
  code = null,
}
```

and have them both encode & decode to the same thing. However it seems if I want to set the code string, I have to do:

```
const changeEventWithCode = {
  source = 'test',
  code = {
    value: 'code',
  },
}
```

I was hoping fromObject ould handle this, but it doesnt - is there any way I can hook in some customisation to do this. Alternatively how can this be achieved with protobufjs using typescript?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can. The wrappers are messages, and I don't think protobuf.js has an option to unbox the values for you.

But [ts-proto](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto#wrapper-types) does! For a `google.protobuf.StringValue code`, it will create a property signature `code: string | undefined`. Sounds like this is what you want.

But it looks like the "optional" label is coming back for proto3. This means you can write:

```proto
message ChangeEvent {
  string source = 1;
  optional string code = 2;
}
```

This is still an experimental feature, added in protoc v3.12.0. And you need a plugin for typescript that supports it.

And there is one: [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/). It will generate the following typescript:

```js
interface ChangeEvent {
  source: string;
  code?: string
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of protobuf-ts.